# How can I install curl inside my container?

Tags: docker, curl

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

#RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN pip install mlflow

RUN pip install sklearn

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
```

When I do

```
docker build -t mycontainer .
```

I get

```
Step 4/4 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
 ---> Running in 5defd9816a22
Reading package lists...
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (13: Permission denied)
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I suspect it is something related with not running as a root?
So how can I install curl in my container from the Dockerfile?

EDIT: I applied the answer that I was given.
Unfortunately it did not work

```
Step 4/7 : USER root
 ---> Running in aa6a1b7a023f
Removing intermediate container aa6a1b7a023f
 ---> 59e87b9598b2
Step 5/7 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
 ---> Running in 4440ce61ebc6
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Reading package lists...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package curl
The command '/bin/bash -o pipefail -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

EDIT2: I tried it in a different network setup and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing a "permission denied" error when `apt` attempts to create `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial`. This is because your process isn't running as `root`; the `jupyter/scipy-notebook` image is configured to run as non-`root` user (it runs as user `jovyan`).

You can change the user under which commands run in your `Dockerfile` with the `USER` directive, like this:

```
FROM jupyter/scipy-notebook

RUN pip install mlflow
RUN pip install sklearn

USER root
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
USER jovyan
```

Note that I've made sure to reset the user back to `jovyan` after running the `apt-get` command.

Comment: I tried but failed. See Edit

Comment: This exact Dockerfile builds without errors. You can see the complete build process [here](https://asciinema.org/a/12LNUiQpEmUgEhKOkpwuSW6fE). If you are experiencing additional errors, please post a new question.

Comment: There must have been something wrong with my network. I came to the office and it worked successfully

Answer (score 3):

Try to install it with `root` as it done in official `jupyter/scipy-notebook` [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/scipy-notebook/dockerfile) and set it back to `$NB_UID`: (see user declaration in official [base docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/base-notebook/dockerfile))

```bash
USER root
# Install packages you need:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl
# Switch back to jovyan to avoid accidental container runs as root
USER $NB_UID
```

Here is the hierarchy of base docker images used by `jupyter/scipy-notebook`:

[jupyter/base-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/base-notebook/dockerfile) -> [jupyter/minimal-notebook](https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/minimal-notebook/dockerfile) -> [jupyter/scipy-notebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/scipy-notebook/dockerfile)

Comment: Please see Edit

Comment: I have created a docker image with Dockerfile from my answer and did not have any problem. Try to delete docker images you have created so far and try once again.

Comment: @KansaiRobot Your original problem should be solved with e.g. my answer. E.g. worked fine in my development environment. The problem you have now does not relate to original question. See https://askubuntu.com/a/91595/1039375 or if it does not help, I suggest to create new question. And please vote up or accept if the answers helped to solve your original question. Thx.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of my answer.

Comment: @larsks Agree, I see we have answered the question almost at the same time. I have adjusted my answer based on the research I have done.